# Can I delete "that of" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I found the following sentence in the dic, and I wonder if *"that of"* is necessary.

> The young coveted career today, is **that of** an entertainer.

I guess "that" refers to career. So my question is, is the following sentence correct?

> The young coveted career today, is an entertainer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete *that of*, you have

> The coveted career is an entertainer.

But an entertainer is a person, and a career is an abstraction meaning one's significant occupation.  As they are different things, they cannot be equivalent with *is*.  You need the relative pronoun *that*, which has as it's antecedent *career*.  In saying

> The career is that of an entertainer

you're saying

> The coveted career is the career of an entertainer.

In other words, two careers are the same.  And that makes sense.